# SyntaxError: Unexpected token import- Node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, webpack, es6-modules

I am trying to code split my app with webpack but webpack is not creating the chunks for my dynamic imports. I found one source here:
https://davidea.st/articles/webpack-typescript-code-split-wont-work
which said I needed to change my module property in my tsconfig file from "commonjs" to "esnext" so the typescript compiler won't reduce my dynamic import statements to Promises, resulting in Webpack not knowing they are dynamic imports and thus not creating dynamic chunks. I followed this and during the compilation I can see the chunks now being created! Whoooo! However, the compiler bugs out, with the error in the title of my question, when trying to resolve the import statements in my express app as those ES imports are not being reduced to something node understands anymore. Does anyone know if this is possible to achieve? I want to use ES imports statements in node but without having the module property in my tsconfig file set to "commonjs". I really don't want to have to refactor all the imports statements to commonJS require statements.

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "esnext",
        "allowJs": true,
        "sourceMap": false,
        "inlineSourceMap": true,
        "strict": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": false,
        "jsx": "react",
        "watch": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node"
}}
```

node version: v8.11.3

I am using ts-node in my npm script to execute my server code:

> "start": "webpack && ts-node -- ./src/service/index.ts --env=prod"

My .babelrc looks like the following:

```
{
    "presets": [
    "react",
    "stage-3",
    [
      "env",
      {
        "modules": false
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "react-hot-loader/babel",
    "syntax-dynamic-import"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Maybe this Babel plugin? https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs

Comment: I have tried that plugin before but unfortunately no luck.

Comment: From investigation online I think it seems that I must use the legacy approach of require.ensure as listed here:
https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#require-ensure
If I want to use dynamic imports with commonJs module syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `ts-node` uses the compiler options in the `tsconfig.json` file in the working directory; you can specify a different `tsconfig.json` file with the `--project` option.  The `tsconfig.json` file you use with `ts-node` must have `module` set to `commonjs` (or omitted, in which case `ts-node` defaults it to `commonjs`) in order for the on-the-fly compilation to generate modules that Node can understand.  You may need to use separate `tsconfig.json` files for the server code you run with `ts-node` and the client code you package with Webpack.

Comment: Oh great I never thought of using another tsconfig file! great idea! I got it working last night using require.ensure to lazy load my components instead of import() but that seems to be a legacy way of doing things as listed here: webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#require-ensure I'll give the second tsconfig file a whirl, thanks

Comment: Worked like a charm Matt! Thank you!